# PHP Regex to trim a file

Tags: php, regex

I need to go through a huge file and remove all strings that appear within `<>` and `(. .)`.

Between those brackets there can be anything: text, numbers, whitespaces etc.

Eg:
`< there will be some random 123 text here >`

I could read the file and use `str_replace` to trim out all those parts, but what I don't know is how can I use regex to pick up the string enclosed in the brackets.

Here's what I want to do:

```
$line = "this should stay <this should not>";
//$trim = do something here using regex so $trim = "<this should not>"

$line = str_replace($trim,"",$line);
```

PS:
The data might be spread across lines:

```
this should stay 
(. this
should
not .)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$nlstr = "{{{".uniqid()."}}}"
$str = str_replace("\n",$nlstr,$str);
$str = preg_replace("/<[^>]*>/","",$str);
$str = preg_replace("/\(\.([^.)]+[.)]?)*\.\)/","",$str);
$str = str_replace($nlstr,"\n",$str);
```

EDIT: edited to enable newlines through a very hackish manner.
EDIT: forgot to escape the fullstops and brackets where necessary.

Comment: I'm not particularly good at regex, but couldn't you simplify the first expression to `<.+?>`?

Comment: I think you must escape the `(` and `.` in your regex.

Comment: @JamWaffles You could, to invoke non-greedy capture. Either way works.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to worry about nesting `(\(\..*?\.\))|(<(.*?>)` will do the job

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-greedy quantifier `.*?` to match a `<` with the closest `>`. Use the `s` modifier to take care of newlines within your string:

```
<?php
$str = 'this should stay < this should not >
this should stay (.this should not.)
this should stay < this
should
not >
this should stay (.this 
should 
not.)';
$str = preg_replace('@<.*?>@s', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('@\(\..*?\.\)@s', '', $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

Output:

```
this should stay 
this should stay 
this should stay 
this should stay
```